# JavaScript: How to pass an object reference from custom context menu

Tags: javascript, reference, href, element

The task at hand is the following: On my web page I intend to include a means of reporting errors which is supposed to be invoked from a custom context menu to make things easier.
What I want to achieve is filling in a particular field of the error report with the contents of the element on which the context menu has been opened.

Now, the code in question (which adds the link for invoking the error reporter) is the following:

```
function ReporterContext(p_menu, p_context, p_elem, p_prestage)
  {
var l_listitem;
var l_link;
var l_text;
var l_lang = document.children[0].attributes['xml:lang'].value;
var l_section;

  if(!p_prestage)
    {
    switch(p_context)
      {
      case 'link':
      case 'ext-link':
        l_section = 'link';
        break;

      default:
        l_section = 'misc';
      }

    l_listitem = document.createElement('li');
    l_link = document.createElement('a');
    l_link.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(InvokeReporter());'); // Object reference supposed to be added here        
    l_text = document.createTextNode(err_outtext[l_section][l_lang]['report']);
    l_link.appendChild(l_text);
    l_listitem.appendChild(l_link);
    p_menu.appendChild(l_listitem);
    }
  }
```

This function is tied into the entire context menu magic when the page is loaded (it is invoked whenever a context menu is opened), and with the above code the error reporter is opened, albeit without the ability to automatically fill in the text contained in the element on which the context menu has been opened.
However, when I modify the line setting the href attribute to pass the element reference like this, I get a syntax error on the console:

```
l_link.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(InvokeReporter(' + p_elem + '));');
```

p_elem is the element reference extracted from the event that triggered the context menu.

Of course, having the element reference passed in double quotes won't do it, either, for obvious reasons...

Now, how do I get the element reference passed to the error reporter so I can use the contents of the referenced element inside a context menu? If there's a way, I don't see it. I'd like to avoid defining a global variable that holds the element reference...

EDIT: The issue could be worked around by encapsulating the function to form a distinct namespace - and then define a namespace-global variable that takes the entity on which the context menu has been opened.
When the error reporter is subsequently invoked, it can read the contents from the element saved earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `href` property to JavaScript code that needs to be evaluated, bind a click handler to `l_link`.

So instead of this:

```
l_link.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(InvokeReporter(' + p_elem + '));');
```

...do this:

```
l_link.setAttribute('href', '#'); // this is just to give it the hyperlink style
l_link.addEventListener('click', function () {
     InvokeReporter(p_elem);
     return false; // to cancel the default hyperlink behaviour
});
```

NB: It is unconventional to give functions names that start with a capital. This is usually done for constructors only. So I would suggest `invokeReporter` as name.

Answer (score 0):

As a viable workaround the entire handler can be wrapped up in an anonymous function, then declare a local variable therein that takes the object on which the menu has been opened.
When the error reporter actually gets invoked, it can take any information from the object that has previously been remembered.